# Calling subtemplates from within a loop in Go template

Tags: go, templates

When I am importing a subtemplate outside of a `{{ range }}` loop, variables are passed successfully inside the imported template:

```
...
 {{ template "userdata" . }}
...
```

(here, I can access my outer templates variables in the inner template `userdata`). So far so good.

However same fashion import doesn't work when being called inside a `{{ range }}` loop:

```
...
{{ range $instance := .Instances }}
- type: instance
  metadata:
    userdata: {{ template "userdata" . }}
...
```

Above ends with error messaging out something like:

```
Error: template: template.tmpl:3:46: executing "userdata" at <XXX>: can't evaluate field XXX in type int`
```

As far as I understand, it shadow my context variable with the loop iterator variable, and so it does not work.

How am I supposed to do it properly?

How do I pass the value of `.` outside of the range loop to template "userdata" when inside a range loop?

Comment: @CeriseLimón: Absolutely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the value of `.` to a variable. Use the variable in the loop:

```
...
{{$x := .}}
{{ range $instance := .Instances }}
- type: instance
  metadata:
    userdata: {{ template "userdata" $x }}
...
```

If `.` is the root value in the template, then use `$` to refer to that value:

```
...
{{ range $instance := .Instances }}
- type: instance
  metadata:
    userdata: {{ template "userdata" $ }}
...
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/9x1pfXID8iI).

Comment: Both options do work!